# How to use last predicted value as feature? NLP NER mission

Tags: python, prediction, scikit-learn, natural-language, feature-engineering

I'm performing NER (Named entity recognition)

For example:

```
Seq: When   Donald   Trump    announced...
Tags: O    B-Person L-Person     O
```

When I'm predicting the word Trump, I have 'word features' for the word 'Trump' which are also considering the context, but I want to use the PREDICTED LABEL of the last word.

It means that I want to use the last predicted tag (Hopefully B-Person) as a feature when I'm predicting the word 'Trump'.

I understood there exists some way to do it using sklearn. 
How can I do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use spacy (it's also the industry standard), it's super easy to do NER [https://spacy.io/usage/examples#training-ner][1] Then you can have all the information like this:

```
# Expected output:
# Entities [('Shaka Khan', 'PERSON')]
# Tokens [('Who', '', 2), ('is', '', 2), ('Shaka', 'PERSON', 3),
# ('Khan', 'PERSON', 1), ('?', '', 2)]
# Entities [('London', 'LOC'), ('Berlin', 'LOC')]
# Tokens [('I', '', 2), ('like', '', 2), ('London', 'LOC', 3),
# ('and', '', 2), ('Berlin', 'LOC', 3), ('.', '', 2)]
```

About the language (Hebrew), it's relatively simple to use it in spacy:

```
from spacy.he import Hebrew

tokenizer = Hebrew().tokenizer

print(list(w.text for w in tokenizer('עקבת אחריו בכל רחבי המדינה.')))
#  ['עקבת', 'אחריו', 'בכל', 'רחבי', 'המדינה.']
```

Comment: I'm doing NER on hebrew, not english

Comment: spacy support Hebrew (lang/he)

Comment: Thanks, but I need to model it myself.  Spacy is not relevant here. . This is a general machine learning question is about - How to use last predicted tag as feature.

Answer (score 0):

I've used the naive approach:

1. normal train & prediction.
2. Getting the predicted previous tags for train and test using the trained classifier
3. Creating new classifier and training it on the new data (the data with previous tags)
4. Loop when predicting X_test[i], getting its tag and adding it as a feature to the next X_test[i+1].

   ```
   clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
   y_pred = clf.pred(X_test)

   y_train_prediction = clf.pred(X_train)

   X_train_with_tag = deepcopy(X_train)
   X_train_with_tag['prev_tag'] = ['O'] + y_train[:-1]

   clf_with_tag <- new clf 
   clf_with_tag.fit(X_train_with_tag, y_train)

   X_test[0]['prev_tag'] = 'O'
   new_y_pred = []

   for i in range(0, len(X_test)-1):
       pred = clf_model_with_tags.predict(X_test=X_test[i])
       X_test[i+1]['prev_tag'] = pred
       new_y_pred.append(pred)


   y_pred_after_tags = clf_with_tag.pred(X_test_with_tag)
   evaluate(y_test, y_pred_after_tags)
   ```